# Pythonのソケット通信のタイムオーバー処理

Tags: python, python3

Pythonのクライアント側の通信で、prosessingのサーバー側からデータが来たらそのまま次の処理に、20秒ほど特にクリックによって送られるデータが来なかった場合同じように次の処理に移りたいのですが、方法がわからず困っています。

時間経過によるフラグにしてしまうと後々フラグが立ってしまったり、while文で回すのも考えたのですが、受信したときに抜け出す方法が分かりませんでした。

**ソースコード:**

```
import subprocess
import time
import socket
from threading import Thread

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 50007
WORK = ""

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #オブジェクトの作成
client.connect((host, port)) #サーバーに接続
client.send("test".encode('utf-8')) #適当なデータ送信

def Get_click():
    response_d = client.recv(4096)
    print (response_d)
    response = response_d.decode('utf-8')
    #届くデータはt01/t02/t03
    return response

time.sleep(2)
print("start")
data = Get_click()

if data.find("t01") >= 0 :
    print(1)
elif data.find("t02") >= 0 :
    print(2)
elif data.find("t03") >= 0 : 
    print(3)
else :  #返答がなければここに割り振られたい
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`socket.settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)でタイムアウト時間を設定する、
というのはいかがでしょうか?

＃`connect`の前に呼び出す必要があります。

#### 追記

タイムアウトした場合、`Get_Click()`の返り値を無効なものにすることで、
`else`条件の処理を行うことができると思います。

```
# 例: タイムアウトしたら、空の値を返す。

def Get_click():
    try:
        response_d = client.recv(4096)
    except socket.timeout:
        response_d = ''
    print (response_d)
    response = response_d.decode('utf-8')
    #届くデータはt01/t02/t03
    return response
```

Comment: こちらのタイムアウト後else部分の処理に移動させる方法はあるのでしょうか？